# How to derive the relationship between energy density, speed, and energy intensity?

Tags: electrostatics, energy

In a black box, the energy density of light is related to the energy intensity.

$$ \rho = \frac{4\pi B}{c}$$

Where $B$ is the intensity of light. How to derive the equation above?

Comment: I see derivations here: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/24-4-energy-in-electromagnetic-waves/ and here: https://phys.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD%3A_Physics_7C_-_General_Physics/10%3A_Electromagnetism/10.4%3A_Electromagnetic_Waves%3A_Light/3._Energy_and_Intensity_of_Light , both of which dont have the 4pi

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a derivation online, but basically you can write the spectral [energy density](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density) (energy density per unit volume), which is the spectral power per unit area divided by the flow speed of flow

$$\rho = \frac{\int B d\Omega}{c}$$

where $B$ is the intensity of the radiation and $\Omega$ is solid angle. Noting that the radiation is isotropic,

$$\rho = \frac{B}{c} \int d\Omega$$

and so

$$\rho = \frac{4\pi B}{c}$$

since $\int_{4\pi} d \Omega = 4\pi$ (integral is over [solid angle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle)).

Comment: Why the energy density can be written as the spectral power per unit area divided by the flow speed of flow? I cannot find any clue from Wikipedia.